# A column is not appearing in GroupBy option when editing view

Tags: document-library, content-type, list-view, caml-query

I have a document library created from a custom content type (which inherits from Document type). The Document Libraries are created via feature activation using CAML in the Elements and a List Definition file.

When I edit the view using the web UI, a particular column is missing from the list of options for GroupBy.

Also, since I inherited from Document content type I thought that the "Created" column would be available so that I could sort by it - but this column is also not available. Is there some CAML markup missing?!?

Note that the column required for the GroupBy DOES appear in the column order list on the list settings page but does not appear on the GroupBy options

***UPDATE***
For the Created column I found that the CAML Field definition had Hidden="TRUE" and changing this to FALSE resolved that column issue.

Your help appreciated.

thanks
KS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the GroupBy column is a MultiChoice column and OOTB sharepoint does not support these for Grouping. Bummer!